# pops (:995) and imaps (:993) and smtps (:465) with TLS. Is the username always encrypted?

Tags: tls

When connecting with my email client using TLS, is the username always encrypted or is it exposed to sniffing (for example, before handshake)?

Comment: Why would authentication happen before a communication channel has been successfully created?

Answer (score 8):

TLS is simply always applied before any data is send. So as you indicate that you are using TLS then the username is indeed encrypted; the handshake happens first.

Beware though that none of those protocols require TLS, quite often they need to be configured to use TLS or STARTTLS. You have however indicated ports that are are expected to offer the service over TLS.

---

In the off-chance that client authentication is used and TLS 1.2 or earlier then the username would be in the certificate, which is sent unencrypted. Apparently that option is present in Thunderbird (see this comment) but I've never actually seen it deployed; **if** you ever need to select a certificate that contains your name then try and use TLS 1.3.

---

Notes:

- TLS creates a secure socket; any user data sent over that socket is protected with the algorithms indicated in the cipher suite;
- Options such as OAuth2 will also use TLS;
- Using a proxy or packet sniffer is highly recommended to test if the TLS connection is being made, a log could also help of course;
- TLS and SSL are synonyms, after SSL 3 we moved onto TLS 1.0 and we're now at TLS 1.3 - although some secure TLS 1.2 configurations are still considered secure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which suggests that STARTTLS also encrypts the username throughout. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Also, as you say I need to configure the client to use TLS. My client (Rmail) has an option to specify using SSL/TLS (but not which one individually), and the server provides a port specificall for TLS. Is option SSL/TLS + using TLS's port enough to force TLS? And in any case, does also SSL encrypt the username throughout?

Comment: Yes, STARTTLS generally is also performed at the start of the connection. It's unlikely that a service that starts on one of the ports defined for TLS protected service will not use TLS. It should however be very easy to either use a proxy or packet sniffer to test if TLS is being utilized, log files will be created, certificates need to be configured etc. I'd always test instead of presume. You could make it part of a pen-test as well. Just thinking along here...

Comment: And does SSL also encrypt the username all the way through (when actually used)?

Comment: TLS doesn't have a username component. TLS is first applied, then the other (mail) protocol is protected by the TLS layer: **all** data in protocols over TLS is encrypted including usernames and passwords. This is also why HTTP basic authentication is still a thing. Does that mean that no data is available to an attacker? Not necessarily, information about the size of the plaintext data and frequency (or even occurrence) of the packets may leak out. But yes, anything protected by TLS is encrypted - assuming that it is correctly applied, of course.

Comment: Your're talking about TLS in your comment but my question is about SSL. Is this because "TLS/SSL" is the same as "TLS", and SSL alone by itself is deprecated? Because my client calls it TLS/SSL and I'm very confused and worried it may use SSL only.

Comment: SSL 3.0 was followed up by TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 and the vastly updated 1.3 specifications. There was discussion in the mailing list to actually call it SSL again. I was one of the persons that thought that was not a good idea, because all the drafts talked about TLS 1.3 making it unnecessarily confusing. What's in a name, eh? Nowadays you should want TLS 1.3 or TLS 1.2 with up-to-date cipher suites if TLS 1.3 is not available.

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using an authentication method inside the application protocol** (eg. password based authentication, Oauth, NTLM) then your username is encrypted by the TLS layer:

```
[SMTP auth.] [IMAP auth.] <- password based authentication, etc.
[SMTP      ] [IMAP      ]
[TLS       ] [TLS       ] <- everything above this is protected (encrypted, etc.)
[TCP       ] [TCP       ]
[IP        ] [IP        ]
```

**If you are using mTLS (certificate-based) authentication**, your username might be transmitted as part of the client [Certificate](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.6) message (a client certificate might have the device name, application name or end user name or similar):

- in TLS 1.2 and below, this message is (usually) transmitted [in cleartext](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#page-36);
- in TLS 1.3, this message is [encrypted by TLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#page-11).

**If you are using Kerberos authentication**, the user identity is going to be encrypted by the TLS layer. **However**, the [KRB_KDC_REQ](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4120#section-5.4.1) request to the Kerberos Authentication Server is transmitted in cleartext (unless [Kerberos over TLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6251) is used). This message includes the client identity (`cname`) in cleartext.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include that spread of possibility.

Comment: I've tried to find any mentions of using mutual authenticated TLS using client certificates (to give the user all the info) for IMAP, but seemingly the more common method of authentication is OAuth2 (which commonly uses server-authenticated TLS if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @Maart FWIW Thunderbird supports the following options for IMAP authentication: "normal password", "encrypted password" (?), "Kerberos / GSSAPI", "NTLM", "TLS Certificate" (i.e. mTLS), "OAuth2"

Comment: Wow, that's somewhat unexpected. I've created smart card ID solutions with X.509 certs but I don't think we've used it for anything but Windows & browser authentication. We did use it for S/MIME of course, but that's applied after login.